# File Sharing: How re-add the Staff group if it was removed?

Tags: permission, user-account, sharing, group

I have MacOS "El Capitan"

About **Sharing - File Sharing**: When a directory is added to be shared through the `Shared Folders` pane, then through the `Users` pane is possible add/remove some *Users* and *Groups* according our needs. It through the `+` and `-` small buttons

But I did realize the following: when the `Staff` group is removed, is not possible re-add the same `Staff` group anymore. It does not appear when `+` is clicked and then through the small dialog window opened and `Users & Groups` option is selected. I tried removing and adding again the same target directory to be shared but nothing.

How solve this situation?

If a new or other directory is added through the `Shared Folders` pane, in the `Users` pane appears already added the `Staff` group such as for the previous directory case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hold down <kbd>Option</kbd> and click the “+” then every group account is shown in addition to users in the list.

Comment: Huge thanks for your valuable answer! :)